# Where would you keep a goat that is living in a manor?

Tags: architecture, medieval, demons

There is a demon disguised as a goat who influences the wealthy lord of a manor into bequeathing him his manor and lands when he dies. He plans on using the land to perform dark rituals, sacrificing people and eating grass. The lord brings the goat to the manor to live out the rest of his days and appoints someone to act as lord on the goat's behalf once he dies. Naturally the goat will need housing and sheltering but I'm not sure what kind. Barn, stable, tower or something else.

This takes place in a medieval setting btw.

Comment: Pet goats are a thing IRL. (They're not even the weirdest pet people can have.) Look around online for recommendations for where to keep pet goats.

Comment: "Perform dark rituals, sacrifice people, and eat grass"... [Classic](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArsonMurderAndJaywalking) .

Comment: @Matthew He needs to fill his stomach somehow :)

Comment: Don't goats [eat](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExtremeOmniGoat) [anything](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FedToPigs)?  It would be in-character...

Comment: [Royal Goat](https://editorial01.shutterstock.com/wm-preview-1500/1174737h/e263f854/queen-elizabeth-ii-visits-caernarfon-castle-wales-britain-shutterstock-editorial-1174737h.jpg) in its natural habitat....long live the Queen

Comment: So you've got people waiting hand and foot...err, hoof...on this goat, catering to his every whim, fetching him tasty dainties, and etc, etc, etc? Meh. Sounds pretty normal to me. Full disclosure: I raise Angora goats, and they've given me permission to say this.

Comment: @LiJun: nice goat. Cashmere, I'd say - not fuzzy enough for an Angora.

Comment: @LiJun - best answer. Based on real life royal interaction. Would UV

Comment: this is a text book example of too story based.  questions here are for worldbuilding not writing your story for you.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest answer, by far, is for the lord of the manor to take up [farming goats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goat_farming). They have been farmed for millennia; they're more work to keep than sheep, but can live on worse land and are more self-reliant. A manor is essentially a large farm with an aristocrat in charge of it, so some land should be available to be used or re-purposed for this.

This provides the demon-goat with concealment, and the chance to breed lots of semi-demonic goats over the years.

Answer (score 10):

**Goats crave luxury.**

http://longisland.news12.com/clip/14926959/the-30-goat-rams-through-glass-door-of-home-sleeps-in-bed

[image: goat in house]

**Goats want meat!**

[image: goat eats meat]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHlTIDu9ODM

**Goats want to mate and fight!.**

Leaving the picture out for this one.  Use your imagination.

In sum the goat would live inside, on a soft bed.  It would spend its days eating, fighting and mating.  It would especially like things it could break by butting, then eat the pieces.

Also spend its days pooping.  It is a goat.  Servants would have to clean up poop.  If they did not do a good job they would be fought or mated with or eaten or all three.

---

Almost forgot:
**Goats love beer!**

[image: goat drinks beer]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MttLz83_C_k

Goat here has clearly done this before.  He spills less than I do.
Demon goat would definitely have much beer, which helps with other aforementioned activities.

Answer (score 1):

Your goat is a male goat.

That changes things a bit.

I lived in the country for a bit and the people across the way raised goats. What I had not realized before was that male goats are not as common to see. That is, when you go to a petting zoo most likely all the adult goats are lady goats.

So here's what I know about the living conditions of one very spoiled male goat.

My neighbors had one intact male goat. Chauncey. Just one. He was kept mostly separated from the others. And you could SMELL him from really far away. They have a kind of musk/urine smell. During the season they pee all over everything including themselves.

Lady goats are useful for milk. Male goats: breeding. They are more aggressive by and large, and more likely to be killed for their meat when they are young.

Male goats can sometimes be kept together, but they have to bond before breeding season, and most of the time they fight and will breed with anything. Including immature females that might be related to them. Goats are social, so sometimes they kept a wether (a castrated male goat) in with Chauncey but put the wether back in with the girls when Chauncey got too rough at the peak of breeding season.

During breeding season he would often forget to eat, so focused was he on the ladies. They had to hand feed him some while being careful of his aggression. (He was a spoiled goat).

Chauncey had his own shack/lean to type thing for shelter that he could wander in and out of, as well as his own acre of land to graze on, and a supply of hay.

They would also give him fruits and veggies cut up like pumpkins and lettuce, but he also loved unsalted tortilla chips and was especially fond of grapes. When it wasn't breeding season, he was still horrible, but during the season, I couldn't go near him. Only certain people could and that SMELL was JUST. UGH, oh boy, I can't even describe... I never got peed on, but I watched him hit my neighbor from a distance that was pretty impressive. (This was through binoculars. In the country where we lived, we would use them to look at our stock in the fields to check on them, and sometimes we would watch the neighbors feed their goats or their dogs herding the goats.)